# how to add subdomain in letsencrypt? I am using docker, nginx, wordpress

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx, subdomain, lets-encrypt

I just added one subdomain and try to expand my existing certificate. But there was an error while renewing the certificate. I added my subdomain on DNS records already. I've tried both CNAME and A but neither works. do I need to try AAAA???

certbot       | Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

certbot       | Plugins selected: Authenticator webroot, Installer None

certbot       | Renewing an existing certificate

certbot       | Performing the following challenges:

certbot       | http-01 challenge for edu.mrtrobotics.com

certbot       | Using the webroot path /var/www/html for all unmatched domains.

certbot       | Waiting for verification...

certbot       | Challenge failed for domain edu.mrtrobotics.com

certbot       | http-01 challenge for edu.mrtrobotics.com

certbot       | Cleaning up challenges

certbot       | Some challenges have failed.

certbot       | IMPORTANT NOTES:

certbot       |  - The following errors were reported by the server:

certbot       |

certbot       |    Domain: edu.mrtrobotics.com

certbot       |    Type:   unauthorized

certbot       |    Detail: Invalid response from

certbot       |    https://www.mrtrobotics.com/content-18/ [149.28.180.33]: "

certbot       |    html>\n\n\n

certbot       |    charset=\"UTF-8\">\ncontent - MRT Robotics | Coding,

certbot       |    Robotics, and STEM Edu"

certbot       |

certbot       |    To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was

certbot       |    entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain

certbot       |    contain(s) the right IP address.

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name mrtrobotics.com www.mrtrobotics.com;

    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        allow all;
        root /var/www/html;
    }

    location / {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name edu.mrtrobotics.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mrtrobotics.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mrtrobotics.com/privkey.pem;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1/edu$request_uri;
        proxy_set_header Host mrtrobotics.com;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name mrtrobotics.com www.mrtrobotics.com;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    root /var/www/html;

    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mrtrobotics.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mrtrobotics.com/privkey.pem;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
    add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
    # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
    # enable strict transport security only if you understand the implications

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off; access_log off;
    }
    location = /robots.txt {
        log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all;
    }
    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}

# Set client upload size - 100Mbyte
client_max_body_size 100M;

# to avoid 504 time out error - defalut is 60s
proxy_send_timeout 180s;
proxy_read_timeout 180s;
fastcgi_send_timeout 180s;
fastcgi_read_timeout 180s;
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
    volumes:
      - ./db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    networks:
      - app-network

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:5.1.1-fpm-alpine
    container_name: wordpress
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db:3306
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=$MYSQL_USER
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_PASSWORD
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress/:/var/www/html
      - ./wordpress/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
    networks:
      - app-network

  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=db
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
    volumes:
    - ./wordpress/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
    networks:
      - app-network

  webserver:
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
    image: nginx:1.15.12-alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
    networks:
      - app-network

  certbot:
    depends_on:
      - webserver
    image: certbot/certbot
    container_name: certbot
    volumes:
      - ./certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
    command: certonly --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html --email elearning@wemakerobot.com --agree-tos --no-eff-email **--expand** -d mrtrobotics.com -d www.mrtrobotics.com **-d edu.mrtrobotics.com**

volumes:
  certbot-etc:
  wordpress:
  db-data:

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Your second `server` block is missing a `location /.well-known/acme-challenge { root /var/www/html; }` block.